# How to use Git-Media

Tags: git

I want to use Git- Media to keep track of One Media file. Can you please tell me how can I do this. Should I install any software. What and all steps I have to follow.

Comment: Have you read the docs? If yes please ask more precise question about something you don't understand or a problem you encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the `README` for `git-media`, which tells you how to install it and set it up, here:

- https://github.com/schacon/git-media#readme

---

In the comments on my answer you've indicated that you're using Windows.  To answer your questions in the comments below:

- Yes, you need to install Ruby, for example with [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/).  (I'd select the options to put the Ruby executables on your path, and also select the option to add an association for `.rb` files.)
- You need to do the steps described in the README to install the gems - `gem install trollop`, etc.
- Add the `git-media/bin` directory to your `PATH`.

You should then be able to run `git-media` from your Git Bash prompt.

Comment: I want to install git-media which i have downloaded from https://github.com/schacon/git-media. I want to install it on windows. Need to install Ruby?. Can you please tell me the steps for installing git-media

Comment: Thank you very much. I have installed it.